# Open a file from an external assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have some XML files that are located in an external assembly.  I have a windows application that references the external assembly, but when I run the windows app and I try to read from the files, it uses the windows app path instead of the assembly path where the files are located.

The external assembly is located in c:\service\tp.dll

The windows app is located in c:\project\windows\bin.

tp.dll contains a method that calls File.OpenRead, but when I execute the windows app and call the method from tp.dll, it is using the windows app path instead of the tp app path.

Comment: Show your work: what does your code look like, what are the file path(s) expected vs actual?

Comment: You mean embedded resource?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you wrote that external assembly and know where everything is supposed to be, have you tried using the Assembly class to reference it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx

I use this class to load files that have a build action of embed in my current executing assembly, but I don't see why you couldn't load another assembly with this class then call the .GetManifestResourceStream(path to the file you want) method.

Here is how I am using it to load embedded data from the current assembly. Change the .GetExecutingAssembly() to the .Load() method instead.

```
            Assembly loader = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var rawstream = loader.GetManifestResourceStream(template);
            byte[] byteArray = rawstream.ReadToEnd();
```

After reviewing the MSDN docs, this is probably what you need to start your assembly reference:

```
      Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load
        ("SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3");
```

Comment: This is the confusing part to me. If my windows app references the external assembly, why do I need to use reflection to access it again?

Comment: Good question, but I don't have an answer to that. I needed the Assembly class to reference an assembly, and it happened to live in reflection so I just went with it.

Comment: I thought about it a bit more - are the files you want from this external assembly embedded inside the assembly? If so, does your external assembly have a public method that can retrieve these files? If not, you may consider adding a public handler that can retrieve these items, which absolves the need to use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

maybe put some more description and some code. important 
- How you are loading the assembly
- How you are accessing the XML file.

Comment: Does this answers the question?

Comment: No, I need more information to see the problem post some code please.

Comment: Then this should be the comment. not answer

Comment: Xaissoft,I agree with Bill solution did this solved your problem?